# Замена хэшей без наличия исходной строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, криптография, любой-язык

Есть ли технологии (библиотеки), которые позволяют без наличия исходной строки заменить хэш на другой. Пример.

Я не хочу хранить персональные данные пользователя, но хочу иметь возможность сменить хэш от строки, которая лежит в базе данных. Хранится хэш от строки `login+password`. Таким образом, я не могу в явном виде попросить пользователя о том, чтобы он сменил пароль, например, в случае компроментации его. Но я хочу иметь возможность самостоятельно это делать.

Я на большой процент уверен, что это можно сделать, поскольку криптостойкие алгоритмы, представляют собой решение уравнений, которые, как правило, имеют несколько решений. А значит, в качестве хэша мы можем взять любое из них.

Нужна библиотека, которая обеспечивает подобный функционал. Преимущество отдают `python`. Библиотеки на других языках также принимаются.

---

[werkzeug](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/src/werkzeug/security.py)

Comment: не понятна проблема - вы сами сгенерили хэш по каким-то правилам, сгенерите по тем же другой и положите. А добыть логин из хэша вы не сможете

Comment: Не совсем понятно, зачем изощряться, подменяя хранимый хэш, тем самым все равно блокируя доступ пользователю. Если вы подозреваете, что произошла компрометация, замените оригинальный хэш на рандомно сгенерированный и заставьте пользователя поменять пароль.

Comment: @splash58 так я и не хочу добывать логин из хэша. Я хочу сгенерить по одному хэшу, другой. Для этого зэша должны выполняться такие же требования как и для предыдущего: `lib.compare(login+password, old_hash) == True`, `lib.compare(login+password, new_hash) == True`

Comment: @strawdog так доступ пользователю закрыт не будет. Будет заблокирован только хэш.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, вы пытаетесь найти другой хэш, который бы соответствовал той же самой исходной строке, и в этом случае вы его не найдете, потому что хэш-функция на то и нужна, чтобы всегда выдавать одинаковый хэш на одну и ту же исходную строку. Иначе это будет другая хэш функция и вы уже не сможете проверить по первой данные пользователя. Если вам нужно, чтобы пароль не изменился, а хэш изменился, используйте одноразовую соль, но в любом случае понадобится исходная строка.

Comment: @Talleyran Вы неправы. Всегда есть соль, которую можно подмешать в хэш. Я добавил в пример библиотеку, которая генерирует разные хэши для одной и той же строки.

Comment: Давайте сразу определимся, хэш функция необратима, т.е. нельзя определить что было хэшированно, и в теории разные значение могут иметь один хэш.

Comment: @pnp2000 да. Но можно ли для существующего хэша сгенерировать ещё один хэш, который ему будет эквивалентен, но не равен? При этом считаем, что исходая строка недоступна.

Comment: И да и нет, насколько я понимаю вы хотите вызвать коллизию хеш функции?

Comment: @pnp2000 нет. Коллизия это вот что `H(x) = H(y)`. Так вот у меня `x=y`. А я хочу `H(x) != H(x)`. Как это возможно? Например, можно задавать хэш функцию, которая зависит от времени или от `seed`. Но для хэш-функций ещё есть `cmp()`, которая умеет сравнивать на равенство результаты `H(x)`. Тогда, я хочу, чтобы `cmp(H(x, t0), H(x, t1)) == 1`.

Comment: Вопрос, есть ли библиотеки, которые умеют `H(x, t)`?

Comment: @hedgehogues, не имея доступа к `x` вы не сможете сгенерировать новый хеш для `x` не подобрав его - на это могут уйти сотни лет) В этом случае обычно генерят новый временный пароль и отправляют его пользователю. После первой успешной попытки залогиниться со временным паролем, пользователя заставляют изменить пароль

Comment: @MaxU так вроде бы эллиптическая криптография должна решать это, не? Там решается эллиптическое уравнение, которое имеет очень много решений. Разве мы не можем взять другое решение для того же `x`? Насколько я понимаю физику этих кривых, они параметризуются по параметру, перебирая который можно генерировать различные хэши.

Comment: @hedgehogues, а как вы возьмёте другое решение не зная `x` ;)

Comment: @MaxU я предполагаю, `x` могут иметь порядок. Этот порядок задаёт функция `H`.

Comment: «хочу иметь возможность сменить хэш от строки, которая лежит в базе данных» — какую задачу вы хотите этим решить?